# Ext JS xtemplate question - check if field exists

Tags: extjs

I have an ExtJS xtemplate that is throwing errors because of the way a json object is returned.

Sometimes the json object has a field `customer` defined, but sometimes it's completely missing from the object.

Obviously, I get an error **customer is not defined** when applying my template to the json where the field is missing.

So my question is:
Is there a way that I can check for an undefined field in an xtemplate?

Like:

```
<tpl if="customer!=undefined">{customer}</tpl>
```

obviously I've tried this but it doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<tpl if="customer == undefined">
    <b>{customer}</b>
</tpl>
```

Comment: How did this work if you need to write it out only if it is defined?

Answer (score 14):

Unless I'm mistaken, you should just be able to do something like the following:

```
<tpl if="customer">
   <b>{customer}</b>
</tpl>
```

Alternatively, you should be able to embed (albeit limited, not sure if my ternary example will work as expected) Javascript into XTemplates like so:

```
{[values.customer]}
{[values.customer ? customer : 'Empty']}
```

Comment: For me works only: {[values.customer ? values.customer : 'Empty']} otherwise I receive error: [INFO][Ext.XTemplate#apply] Error: customer is not defined

Comment: This would work too: `{[values.customer || 'Empty']}`